# OS available on Gs2

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Ubuntu phone is available on gs2 ?
Wifi + 3G + sms and call ?

Sorry for my languages because i'm very bad in English x) !

Answer (score 0):

If it is the [Samsung Galaxy S2](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/i9100), not all things are working yet: See detail at the previous link.